# Class method don't exists (throwing fatal error) - But it exist

Tags: php, oop, methods

I don't know why, but PHP triggers a Fatal Error because a Class Method doesn't exist.
But it clearly exists!

left.phtml:

```
<?php
    $block = Block::getBlock('core/sidebar_modules');
    foreach($block->getSidebar('left') AS $key => $value)
    {
        $_block = explode('_',$value->getName());
        if(isset($_block[1]))
        {
            $_block[1] .= '_widget';
        }
        $loadBlock = Block::getBlock(implode('/',$_block)); // returns instance of Visio_Blog_Block_Recent_Widget
        Debug::var_dump($loadBlock);
        /*
            returns:

            object(Visio_Blog_Block_Recent_Widget)#33 (0) {
            }
        */
        echo $loadBlock->widgetContent();
        /*
            returns:

            Fatal error: Call to a member function widgetContent() on a non-object in E:\docroot\vhosts\zend.local.host\htdocs\app\design\default\templates\left.phtml on line 13
        */

        Debug::print_r(get_class_methods($loadBlock));
        /*
            returns:

            Array
            (
                    [0] => __construct
                    [1] => widgetContent
            )
        */
    }
?>
```

Widget.php (Visio_Blog_Block_Recent_Widget)

```
Class Visio_Blog_Block_Recent_Widget
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function widgetContent()
    {
        return 'content';
    }

}
```

I have no clue why this happens?

Is it possible that this is an Error off my View Class while implementing nested view Templates.

I built the framework from scratch.

Comment: Can you please alo post the getBlock() function ?

Comment: `public static function getBlock($block)
  {
   $blockName = self::getBlockName($block);
   if(class_exists($blockName))
   {
    self::$_instances[$blockName] = new $blockName();
    return self::$_instances[$blockName];
   }
   return null;
  }`

Comment: And so `$loadBlock` is not `null` before  `echo $loadBlock->widgetContent();`

Comment: No it isn't **null** till var_dump prints out the Object.

Comment: Okay, found the problem. There were 2 Database records in that foreach loop. The first one don't exist so it triggers that error.

Answer (score 0):

from the error it looks like that `$loadBlock` does not contain an instance of  `Visio_Blog_Block_Recent_Widget` or any class, for that matter.

So the problem is around assigning.